# Permission denied (403) when trying to create calendar event

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, adal, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to integrate to Office365 API through JavaScript with adal.js and jQuery (OAuth implicit flow), but I am having issues trying to create a calendar event for my user. My existing code works fine when *retrieving* emails and calendar events, but when I try to *create* a calendar event, I consistently get a "403 - Forbidden" response.

The code is live and working at http://oauth.idippedut.dk/oauth.html. I am accessing the Office 365 API endpoint at https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events .

My configuration for "Delegated permissions" on the app in our Office365/Azure tenant Active Directory is this:
[image]

The configuration for "Application permissions" on the app in our Office365/Azure tenant Active Directory is this:
[image]

The jQuery request is this:

```
var event = {
    "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
    },
    "Start": {
        "DateTime": "2016-01-21T18:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "End": {
        "DateTime": "2016-01-21T19:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "Attendees": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Address": "jesper@lundstocholm.dk",
                "Name": "Janet Schorr"
            },
            "Type": "Required"
        }
    ]
};

// Create calendar events
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: postCalenderEndpoint,
    data: JSON.stringify(event),
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },

}).done(function (data) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function (err) {
    jQuery("#loginMessage").text('Error calling REST endpoint: ' + err.statusText + '\n' + err.responseText);
});
```

The configuration of jQuery is this:

```
var resource = 'https://outlook.office.com';
var postCalenderEndpoint = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events';
var clientID = '28a707a5-0f11-4d93-8b88-6a918544da14';
var tenantName = '365projectum.onmicrosoft.com';
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: tenantName,
    clientId: clientID,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
});
```

And the resulting HTTP-request is this:

```
Host: outlook.office.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Bearer <my token>
Referer: http://oauth.idippedut.dk/oauth.html
Content-Length: 386
Origin: http://oauth.idippedut.dk
Connection: keep-alive

{"Subject":"Discuss the Calendar REST API","Body":{"ContentType":"HTML","Content":"I think it will meet our requirements!"},"Start":{"DateTime":"2016-01-21T18:00:00","TimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"},"End":{"DateTime":"2016-01-21T19:00:00","TimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"},"Attendees":[{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"jesper@lundstocholm.dk","Name":"Janet Schorr"},"Type":"Required"}]}
```

I am really puzzled to why I get the 403, since everything should be set up correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :-)

/Jesper

Comment: I looked a bit closer at the API reference and changed the "resource" configuration to https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite, and now the code returns an error like this: "ADAL Error Occurred: AADSTS50001: The application named https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite was not found in the tenant named 365projectum.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. " . So that got me nowhere :-(

Comment: It has definitely to do something with the token. Microsoft keeps upgrading/updating their APIs. Due to this fact you should maybe consider to use the graph endpoint.

Comment: I am getting the same issue with the resource graph.microsoft.com. Also all the permissions are given in the portal like calendars.readwrite,calendars.read, mailboxsettings.read, mailboxsettings.readwrite

Answer (score 2):

You configured delegated permissions for Microsoft Graph, but call the Outlook endpoint. You need to do either of:
1. change your app configuration to have delegated permissions for Outlook/Office 365 Exchange Online.
2. change your app to use the Microsoft Graph endpoint (graph.microsoft.com), i.e. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events and keep the current app configuration.

Answer (score 1):

try "https://graph.microsoft.com" as the resource to get the (right) token.

Best regards,

AJ

Answer (score 0):

Did you originally register the application requesting the permission "Read user and shared calendars", and then later add the permission "Have full access to user calendars"?  If yes, you might be in the situation where users have consented to the former permission, and since that consent is in place they are never further asked to consent to the new permission you added.  Which would explain why your app can read, but can't write.

You would only be in this situation with users who consented BEFORE you added the new permission, and only if users were in fact consenting.  Users would not have to consent if you registered the app as an admin, and were signing in with users in the same tenant as the admin.  Users WOULD have to consent if you registered the app as an ordinary user, or if the app is a multi-tenant app.

If either of the two are the case, the simple way to see if this is the problem is to try using the app as a brand new user who hasn't consented before.  This new user would consent to all the permissions requested by the app.  Note that if this is an admin-consent app, then you'll need a net new tenant to consent.

If this DOES solve the problem, then you need to get your existing users to go through a step where you send a new OAuth authorize request using the prompt=consent parameter, to get them to consent again.